# Textures Showing Up In Rendered View But Not Texture View

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I was following Blender Guru's tutorial on UV unwrapping. 
However, I have a problem: my textures will show in render view mode but not texture view. (Right at the bottom next to the select menu that says Object Mode). In texture view, it looks just like solid view. Also can anyone find a way to keep the whole object lit and visible?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the object selected :

From the **Properties panel** open the **Object tab** and then from the **Display** menu change the **Max Draw Type** from Solid to **Textured**.

Now you should be able to see your texture when the viewport shading is set to Texture.

[image]